# Creating a dictionary from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

```
text="we are in pakistan and love pakistan and olx"
dict1={"pakistan": "COUNTRY", "olx": "ORG"}
```

I need to match the key in the text, if it exists store the indices of that word as keys in new dictionary where as the value should be the same as in dict1 for that particular word, for eg the output should be like this:

```
dict2={[10:17]:"COUNTRY",[27:34]:"COUNTRY","[40:42]:"ORG"}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @kingkupps so far, i have made a list out of all the keys and matched it with the text, for now I am able to get the key and and its indices in the text, but I am confused what to do for the dict2 part.
'code' dict1={"pakistan": "COUNTRY", "olx": "ORG"}
keyword_list=[*dict1]
print(keyword_list)
all_text = 'we are in pakistan and love pakistan and olx'
index_dict = {}
for item in keyword_list:
    if item in all_text:
        index_dict[item] = [all_text.index(item), all_text.index(item) + len(item) -1]

print(index_dict)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I have to address that your expected outcome which is having lists, which are not hashable, as the key of a dictionary is not possible. See https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys

The way to produce something similar is to use the [re library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re
text="we are in pakistan and love pakistan and olx"
dict1={"pakistan": "COUNTRY", "olx": "ORG"}
dict2 = {}
for key, value in dict1.items():
    matched_all = re.finditer(key,text)
    for matched in matched_all:
        dict2[matched.span()] = value
print(dict2)
```

This will give you:

```
{(10, 18): 'COUNTRY', (28, 36): 'COUNTRY', (41, 44): 'ORG'}
```